# Syncing / sending Google Maps landmarks to Android Maps

Tags: sync, google-maps, google-maps-navigation, maps

I can save Google Maps landmarks on the desktop browser maps.google.com service to my own maps. However is it possible to sync / send these maps to Android Maps?

- I will look a destination landmarks beforehand on my computer
- I sync them to phone
- When I arrive to a destination (city) I can use my Android to navigate around

If this is not Google Maps I am free to use alternative services as long as desktop mobile sync connection exists.

Answer (score 1):

On Android 4.0 at least, the "maps" app has a "My Maps" layer.  It will show you your saved maps.

On older versions of Android (sorry, but I can't confirm this) I think there's a separate "My Maps" app.

Comment: Does 4.x sync? 2.x has My Favorites.